# Find latest files from directory

Tags: python, unique, glob

I am trying to find files present in a particular directory after matching the pattern for the file names in a list using glob function. But this is not returning any output. Below is the code

```
FileDetail=list(SourceFileName.split(',')     
  print(FileDetail)   
  for line in FileDetail:    
   FileList = SourceFileDirectory+line+"*.txt" 
   print(FileList)
   for file_name in glob.glob(FileList):    
    print(file_name)
```

#Current Values#
FileDetail list will have values as "[abc,xyz]"
FileList will have below values

C:\Users\akash\Desktop\Python\SourceFile\ABC*.txt
C:\Users\akash\Desktop\Python\SourceFile\XYZ*.txt

Source File Directory will have below files
ABC01242021.txt
ABC01252021.txt
XYZ01242021.txt
XYZ01252021.txt

Currently file_name is coming as blank

#Expected Output#
ABC01252021.txt
XYZ01252021.txt

Answer (score 0):

Manually constructing paths is error-prone. Try `os.path` or `pathlib` packages.

The filename seem fixed-size, so direct `Path` comparison with `max()` is possible.
The result `latest_file_name` is a `Path` object.

If a `str` is prefered, use `str(latest_file_name)` to cast it to a `str`.

```py
from pathlib import Path

FileDetail = list(SourceFileName.split(','))
for line in FileDetail:
    print("Pattern", line)

    try:
        latest_file_name = max(Path(SourceFileDirectory).glob(f"{line}*.txt"))
    except ValueError:
        # max() raise ValueError if the input is empty
        print("No file matches the pattern", line)
        continue

    print(latest_file_name)
    print(latest_file_name.name)  # the name attribute contain the file basename.
```